# On standard form of corners

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(M, \tau)$ be a $\mathrm{II_{1}}$ factor equipped with the faithful normal tracial state $\tau$ acts on $L^{2}(M,\tau)$ is in standard form. The question is: if we consider vN algebras $PMP(P\in M)$ acting on $PL^{2}(M,\tau)$ and $QM(Q \in M')$ acting on $QL^{2}(M,\tau)$,  are these vN algebra in standard form or not?

Comment: Could you write your last sentence more carefully (don't mind splitting it into two sentences)?

Comment: What is your _definition_ of a "standard form"?  What have you tried to do?  For example, for me a "standard form" involves a "modular conjugation" $J$.  What is the modular conjugation on $PL^2$ or $QL^2$?

Comment: Standard form means there exist $J: L^{2}(M, \tau)\rightarrow L^{2}(M, \tau)$ such that J is the antiunitary, defined on dense set $J(\hat{x})=\hat{x^{*}}$ where $\hat{x}$ is the copy of $M$ in $L^{2}(M,\tau)$ such that the equation $JMJ=M'$ holds, where commutant is taken in $L^{2}(M, \tau)$, $x:\mapsto Jx^{*}J$ is the map from $M$ to $M'$

Comment: Okay.  So what is your candidate for the map $J$ on $PL^2$, for example??

Comment: I was thinking of $PJP$ but don't know that will work or not.

Comment: Is P an arbitrary element of M, as claimed?  Or perhaps it is meant to be a projection, or a central projection?  If P is an arbitrary element of M, exactly how is PMP a von Neumann algebra?  Same question for Q.

Comment: OK, if you say you don't know whether PJP will work, write down the conditions that PJP would have to satisfy in order for it to be a modular conjugation, and then tells us where you get stuck

Comment: @Dimitri obviously P and Q are  projections that's why they are said to be corner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since the OP seems not to have engaged with the hints in the comments, and has been asking a series of small questions without signs of progressing to working things out themselves